# Copying content from one worksheet to another if value matches another value?

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I'm trying to import product variants and their prices with two csv files:

1. **config.csv** (where I'm trying to place the variants/prices)
2. **variants.csv** (where the information on the variants exists)

The format I need is `size::3' x 5':-120` for example.

This is what **config.csv** looks like:

```
    SKU        super_attribute_pricing
 VTG100-130  
 VTG100-730
 ....
```

This is what **variants.csv** looks like:

```
    sku         size      price
VTG100-130    3' x 5'    -120
VTG100-130    4' x 6'     -80
VTG100-130    5' x 8'      0
VTG100-730    3' x 5'    -120
VTG100-730    4' x 6'     -80
....
```

How can I use the 3 values above and put it in the format `size::3' x 5':-120` as long as the sku in **variants.csv** matches the sku in **config.csv**?

I tried this for value in `super_attribute_pricing` column:

```
="size::"&[variants.csv]variant!B2&":"&[variants.csv]variant!C2&";"
```

But the above does not consider whether the value in sku column in **variants.csv** matches the sku in **config.csv**. I want to copy those values as long as the SKU's match up - otherwise I want to move to the next row and coninue comparing until it ends.

How to do this with VBA?

Comment: I don't understand.... You have 3 values for `VTG100-130` in your variants sheet... Will you have 3 rows for that in your config? Or do you just take the first one? It seems config already has that first column... If that is the case, which one from the variants sheet should it take??

Comment: Just the first one. The values are actually like `vtg100-130-3, vtg100-130-4` but I figured removing the size part (`-3, -4` etc.) would make it easier to do the matching.

Comment: Have a look at the `Vlookup()` function... Might do exactly what you need, then...

Answer (score 1):

Here's the VBA code to solve your problem.  Call it by using a function in the cell you want the description based in by using the following format:

=GetSizes(A2,[variants.csv]variant!$A$2:$A$6)

The first parameter is the part to lookup and the second parameter is the absolute list of parts from your sizes table (variants)

This function call is assuming you are calling it from the config.csv sheet and that your table's first data row is in A2 on each workbook respectively.  Change sheets or cell addresses appropriately.  The way the code is written you only need to pass the list of Part numbers.  The offset will look up the information from the size and price columns for you.

```
Function GetSizes(rngValue As Range, rngLookup As Range) As String

   Dim strSizes As String
   Dim strLookup As String
   Dim rngTemp As Range
   Dim cellval As Range

   Set rngTemp = rngLookup
   strLookup = rngValue.Value
   strSizes = "size::"


   For Each cellval In rngTemp
     If cellval.Value = strLookup Then
       strSizes = strSizes & cellval.Offset(0, 1).Value & ":" & cellval.Offset(0, 2).Value & ";"
     End If
   Next
   If strSizes = "size::" Then strSizes = ""
   If Right(strSizes, 1) = ";" Then strSizes = Left(strSizes, Len(strSizes) - 1)
   GetSizes = strSizes

End Function
```

Note that if there is no matching part number it will return an empty string.

Good luck.